# Is using Django's ListView and get_queryset secure?

Tags: django

I'm using the class based ListView and get_queryset to populate a list of objects assigned to an organization. This code is working well and limits users to only see matters belonging to their organization. My question is whether there are any security flaws in creating the list like this? Specifically, should I be populating the list differently?

matters.views:

```
class MatterListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Matters
    template_name = 'matters/matters.html'
    context_object_name = 'matters'
    ordering = ['-start_date']
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(organization=self.request.user.organization)
```

Comment: the process you have followed is pretty much standard. But it would be great if you could explain what kind of `security flaws` you are concerned about.

Comment: Can a user inject (not sure if I'm using that right) data through the address bar that would give them the ability to see matters (objects) assigned to other organizations?

Comment: Nope, a user can't inject anything through address bar.

Comment: Okay and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to practice to use class-based list view. You can also use the function-based view for the list.
But there several benefits to using class-based view over function based view like class-based view can be easily extended, reuse code.

The security issue broadly handles by Django itself. So you don't need to panic about this.

If you want to protect your data more speficly like currently, you limit data to logged in user, then you can write custom mixin very easily in class-based view.